# Setting onchange listener for textfield in j2me

Tags: java-me, textfield, onchange, midp, lcdui

Is it possible to set a onchange listener to the textfield in j2me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure. Use [ItemStateListener](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/ItemStateListener.html) for that:

```
// below assumes that 'form' contains 'textField' which changes you want to listen to
form.setItemStateListener(new ItemStateListener() {
    public itemStateChanged(Item item) {
        if (item != textFiled) {
            return; // ignore other items
        }
        System.out.println("contents: [" + textField.getString() + "]");
    }
});
```

It is worth keeping in mind details of how `itemStateChanged` is invoked per the API docs:

> ...when the user ...enters or modifies the value in a TextField...
>
> It is up to the device to decide when it considers a new value to have
>   been entered into an Item. For example, implementations of text
>   editing within a TextField vary greatly from device to device.
>
> In general, it is not expected that the listener will be called after
>   every change is made. However, if an item's value has been changed,
>   the listener will be called to notify the application of the change
>   before it is called for a change on another item, and before a command
>   is delivered to the Form's CommandListener. For implementations that
>   have the concept of an input focus, the listener should be called no
>   later than when the focus moves away from an item whose state has been
>   changed. The listener should be called only if the item's value has
>   actually been changed.
>
> The listener is not called if the application changes the value of an
>   interactive item.